# Lagging when I am about to enter my password during user login

Tags: 22.04, login, password, users, systemd-logind

After I have booted my laptop, when I am about to login to my user, I cannot enter my password for some time. I keep on typing, but I cannot enter my password. After sometime, I am able to enter my password.